# Object Oriented Programming Syntax Question, passing a class method from one file to another

Tags: javascript, object, oop, methods, commonjs

I have two files,
employee.js

```
const Manager = require('./manager.js');


let manager = new Manager();

class Employee {
    constructor(name, title, salary, boss=null)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.boss = boss;
        manager.addEmployee(this.Employee);
    }
}




module.exports = Employee;
```

And manager.js

```
const Employee = require('./employee.js');

class Manager extends Employee {
    constructor(name, salary, title, boss=null) {
        // this.name = name;
        // this.title = title;
        // this.salary = salary;
        // this.boss = boss;
        super(name, salary, title, boss);
        this.managedEmployees = [];
    }

    addEmployee(Employee) {
        this.managedEmployees.push(Employee);
    }
}

let annie = new Manager('annie', 100000, 'Director');
let alvy = new Employee('alvy', 75000, 'Analyst', annie);

console.log(annie);

module.exports = Manager;
```

I am desperately trying to find what syntax would allow me to take the addEmployee(Employee) method and call it in the constructor of the Employee class. I want Manager to be the child of Employee and have an array of all the employees under the manager. The method is pushing into the array but I cannot figure out what I should be doing for `console.log(annie);` to end up with this input

```
<ref *1> Manager {
  name: 'Annie',
  salary: 100000,
  title: 'Director',
  manager: null,
  employees: [
    Employee {
      name: 'Alvy',
      salary: 75000,
      title: 'Analyst',
      manager: [Circular *1]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You don’t define a `this.Employee` property. Did you mean `this`? What is the expected result? What is wrong with the current output?

Comment: I was getting either Manager is not defined or ```TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null.``` It wasn't really one error more so that I got a bunch of errors but the below answer given fixed it with the removal of the top two lines of code in employee.js

Answer (score 2):

Setup your Employee class like this:

```
    class Employee {
        constructor(name, title, salary, boss=null)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.title = title;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.boss = boss;
            if (boss) {
                boss.addEmployee(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

You're passing in an instanceof Manager, so if it's not null you can call a method on that. Notice that you want to just pass `this` as the input to `addEmployee`, as `this.Employee` is trying to access a property or method in that class which doesn't exist.

Console output will look something like this:

```
    Manager {
        name: "annie",
        title: 100000,
        salary: "Director",
        boss: null,
        managedEmployees: [
            Employee {
                name: "alvy",
                title: 75000,
                salary: "Analyst",
                boss:Manager {...}
            }
        ]
    }
```

You will also notice that you have the order of parameters swapped for title/salary on your Employee constructor.

Comment: This solved it I had to get rid of the ```const Manager = require('./manager.js'); let manager = new Manager();``` and then I input your if (boss) code and it worked! thank you I have been so confused on this syntax, this isn't the whole project but I appreciate you helping me go forward.

Comment: @MikelFisher I would recommend having an array of Employee ID's instead of the whole Employee object. That way it will take up less size, and you only have to edit the data in one place.

Comment: @MikelFisher Great. Make sure you saw my edits as well. If that's solved all your issues, please accept the answer.

Comment: @Invizi As currently written, the program doesn't take up any more memory than an array of IDs would because `Manager` will just have a reference to the `Employee` object, and not a copy of the whole thing. I agree that's not necessarily best practice, particularly as you start manipulating employees, or passing Manager object around, but it's not always going to be a memory hog.

Comment: @Mordred I will make sure to, one question, how do I accept an answer? I am a noob to this platform and coding and I cannot seem to find a button besides Answer your question which seems to prompt me for the answer. Also how would I make an array of the employee ID's? Just the same way I did the manage employees?

Comment: @MikelFisher Should be a grey check mark near the up/down vote buttons on my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers